# Is there a rule concerning the positioning of Stations of the Cross in Catholic churches?

Tags: catholicism, lent, devotion

Way of The Cross is a devotion followed by Catholic Church especially during Lent. It comprises of 14 Stations, the representative images of which are placed  on the  walls of the church. The pattern of positioning of the Stations from first  to 14th is anti- clockwise , with Station 1 starting from the right of the
Altar following Versus Populum tradition  . One seldom sees a clock- wise positioning. My question is: Is there a rule concerning the positioning of Stations of the Cross in Catholic churches ?